# How do i log into redmine using rest api

Tags: jquery, redmine

I am creating a custom PM tool using **Redmine API**. I need to create the login function using jquery. I am lost, Please guide me to,

- post username and password to server
- if they match with the redmine db
- view the relent user page

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("button").click(function(){

  var username = $("#login").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();

      $.post("http://login:faabf7eed439408ea9ac2b6ead7941ef6c70c7b7@localhost.com/redmine/users.json",
   {login:login, password:password}, 
     function(data){console.log(data);

   })


});

</script>
```

```html
<form role="form">
                           
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="login"  name="login" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="password"  name="password" type="password" value="" required>
  </div>

  <input  type="submit" value="Login">
                                
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one code. This is test using the same server as Redmine.

```
$.post('http://redmineServer/redmine/login', {username:'username',password:'password'},function(responsePage,statusText,result){
     console.log(responsePage);
})
```